# Devilbox - error, "No Host DNS record found. " even after adding folder name in /etc/hosts/

Tags: networking, server, dns, localhost

I am using Devilbox and have been learning through documentation on how to work with it, I have created a folder inside /data/www/ inside devilbox folder and before that I have excluded the mention of "htdocs" from .env file.

Now when I made the changes by adding :

127.0.0.1 hi.local

inside /etc/hosts by using sudo nano, I am still seeing the same error "No host DNS found". I dont know what I am missing out.